# PySpark Aggregate rows into MapType column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have two columns in pyspark dataframe, "id" and "map_values".
Example:

```
id,map_values
1,{"a" -> "b", "c" -> "d"}
1,{"e" -> "f", "g" -> "h"}
2,{"a" -> "b"}
```

How can I aggregate over "id" column and still get MapType?
Desired result:

```
id,map_values
1,{"a" -> "b", "c" -> "d", "e" -> "f", "g" -> "h"}
2,{"a" -> "b"}
```

Answer (score 0):

An idea is to start by exploding the maps with `explode` to obtain one row per key value pair (note that spark does not create a struct but two columns named `key` and `value`). Then we can group by `id` and collect lists of struct containing key value pairs. Finally we use `map_from_entries` to transform the list of key value pairs to a map.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# creating the sample dataframe
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1,{"a": "b", "c": "d"}), (1,{"e" : "f", "g" : "h"}), (2,{"a" : "b"})],
    ['id', 'map_values']
)

df\
    .select("id", F.explode("map_values"))\
    .groupBy("id")\
    .agg(F.collect_list(F.struct("key", "value")).alias("map_values"))\
    .withColumn("map_values", F.map_from_entries("map_values"))\
    .show(truncate=False)
```

```
+---+--------------------------------+
|id |map_values                      |
+---+--------------------------------+
|1  |{a -> b, c -> d, e -> f, g -> h}|
|2  |{a -> b}                        |
+---+--------------------------------+
```